# Новая служба не ответила на запрос своевременно

Tags: c#, служба

Смысл в чем. Создаю абсолютно пустую службу:

*projectinstaller.cs*

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace mrserivce
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller;
        private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
            serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService;

            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = MainService.MyServiceName;
            this.Installers.AddRange(new Installer[] { serviceProcessInstaller, serviceInstaller });
        }
    }
}
```

*mainservice.cs*

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace mrserivce
{
    public class MainService : ServiceBase
    {
        public const string MyServiceName = "mrserivce";

        public MainService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

*kernel.cs*

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace mrserivce
{
    static class Kernel
    {    
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { new MainService() });
        }
    }
}
```

Далее я компилирую ее в Release, открываю cmd от админа, с помощью cd перехожу в каталог с экзешником, и пишу:

```
sc create testService binPath=mrservice.exe type=own start=auto
sc start testService
```

После чего (мгновенно) выпадает ошибка:

```
[SC] StartService: ошибка: 1053:

Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно.
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте установить через InstallUtil.exe

Comment: Разница, на самом деле, не большая. Разве что через InstallUtil в одной сборке могут работать несколько служб.

Comment: ProjectInstaller в вопросе лишний - `sc.exe` его не использует

Comment: @PavelMayorov А я то думаю, зачем sc нужно указывать и юзера, и описание и имя, если все это прописано в инстайлере. Спасибо, буду ставить через InstallUtil.

Comment: @EduardGushchin не надо, sc.exe более мощный

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как быть с множеством служб в одной сборке?

Comment: @EduardGushchin через powershell или реестр их поставить можно

Comment: Но такой ситуации я еще ни разу не встречал. Лучше скажите, что будете делать когда понадобится установить две копии одной и той же службы с разными настройками?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Хм, ну в таком случае логичнее будет использовать sc.

Comment: @EduardGushchin вот-вот. А я видел и такое решение: в солюшене 5 проектов служб и 1 библиотека. В службах - Program и ProjectInstaller, остальное - в общей библиотеке...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле проблема была в путанице с файловой системой. Как известно, из за перехода на x64 все 32-битные сборки при обращению к system32 редиректятся в SysWOW64. Поэтому когда сборка с сервисом находится в system32, при установки sc начинает искать службу в SysWOW64 (ее там, естественно, нет). Из за чего и происходит эта ошибка.

Comment: *Осталось понять, зачем вообще было копировать сборку в system32...* :-)

Comment: Переубеждать заказчика бессмысленно:)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить Thread или Task в метод onStart

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartFunction));
   thread.Start();
}
private void StartFunction()
{
    // какой-то код
}
```